# Unable to pass Email as context using Google Auth

Tags: google-plus, google-authentication

We are currently hitting the following endpoints via Google Auth.
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.emails.read

This suddenly stopped working after the weekend. When populating the token, the email is null, however other attributes are being populated.

Received an email saying that Google Plus currently has a service issue, however when asking Doravil from google support, they referred me here.

Is anyone else having this issue?

This is a business critical application so if anyone has this issue, please let me know!